# Unpacking a lambda function I found to understand what it is doing python

Tags: python, lambda

I am implementing the first half of the [Grahm Scan convex hull algorithm](https://leetcode.com/problems/erect-the-fence/discuss/103300/Detailed-explanation-of-Graham-scan-in-14-lines-(Python)) to find a noncomplex polygon from my list of points.

My code is currently

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import random

def sortPoints(points):
    # Computes the cross product of vectors p1p2 and p2p3
    # value of 0 means points are colinear; < 0, cw; > 0, ccw

    # Find the smallest left point and remove it from points
    start = min(points, key=lambda p: (p[0], p[1]))
    points.pop(points.index(start))

    # Sort points so that traversal is from start in a ccw circle.
    points.sort(key=lambda p: (slope(p, start), -p[1], p[0]))

    print points

def slope(p1, p2):
    return 1.0*(p1[1]-p2[1])/(p1[0]-p2[0]) if p1[0] != p2[0] else float('inf')

if __name__ == '__main__':

    templist = [(0,0), (1,5), (6,6), (3,3), (6,1)]
    random.shuffle(templist)
    sortPoints(templist)
```

The code works and the sample returns [(6, 1), (6, 6), (3, 3), (1, 5)] or a list of ccw points.

I am after clarification of the

```
-p[1], p[0]
```

at the end of the lambda function

```
points.sort(key=lambda p: (slope(p, start), -p[1], p[0]))
```

Comment: What exactly needs clarifying? Python's `sort` sorts a tuple sequentially: take each `(slope(p, start), -p[1], p[0])`, sort first look at the first element, then the second, then the third.

Comment: So `(slope(p, start), -p[1], p[0])` are all in the scope of the sort function and not the lambda expression? That makes a lot more sense but just to clarify.

`sort()` is sorting by the `slope(p, start)` then `-p[1]` and finally `p[0]` are the second two for tie breaking? or is the list resorted with the first the lowest priority?

Comment: Yes, the second 2 are tie-breakers (consecutively).

Comment: "in the scope of the sort function" What do you mean by that?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga just that they are inputs to the sort function and not the lambda function.

Comment: They *are not inputs to the `sort` method*. The `slope` is a global variable, `p` is a parameter to the lambda, and `start` is a free variable of the lambda function (whose scope is local to the `sortPoints` function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python's sort method will first sort based on `slope(p, start)` then on `-p[1]` and then on `p[0]` (for tie-breaking).
To be more specific to your query, `p[1]` is the y-coordinate, and `-p[1]` will sort based on the descending order of the y-coordinates.
Similarly, `p[0]` is the x-coordinate, and so the sorting will be performed on the ascending order of the x-coordinates.
Hope that helps.

Comment: That does make sense. Just to clarify `sort()` is sorting by the `slope(p, start)` then `-p[1]` and finally `p[0]` are the second two for tie breaking? or is the list resorted with the first `slope(p, start)` the lowest priority? Such that the final sort is based on `p[0]` and ties are resolved by the first two variables?

Comment: Yes, the second and third sort parameters are intended for tie-breaking.

Comment: thank you the results I am getting make much more sense now.